# Retrieving oAuth scopes from an installed connected app

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

In the portal, it is easy under the setup console, find a specific application, and see all of its **Application Permissions**. For example:

[image]

However, when querying the API for `ConnectedApplications`, `PermissionsSet`, `ObjectPermissions` and others I can't find this data.

What is the best way to fetch the **Application Permissions**?

Comment: You could check Metadata API and ConnectedAppOauthConfig, property Scope - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm#connectedAppAttribute_title

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is within the [ConnectedApplication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm#connectedAppOauthPolicy_title) metadata in the `scopes` field within the `oauthConfig` field.

You mention "querying" it - but, you won't get any of the scope info with SOQL; however, you can easily retrieve it with the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm) `retrieve()` call (and if needed in apex, can look at utilizing [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to interact with the same API).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ConnectedApp</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

And within the returned metadata file you'll see scope (added all as an example).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedApp xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <contactEmail>test@testing.com</contactEmail>
    <label>Kris</label>
    <oauthConfig>
        <callbackUrl>https://www.test.com</callbackUrl>
        <consumerKey>the key will be here</consumerKey>
        <isAdminApproved>false</isAdminApproved>
        <isConsumerSecretOptional>false</isConsumerSecretOptional>
        <isIntrospectAllTokens>false</isIntrospectAllTokens>
        <isSecretRequiredForRefreshToken>true</isSecretRequiredForRefreshToken>
        <scopes>Basic</scopes>
        <scopes>Api</scopes>
        <scopes>Web</scopes>
        <scopes>Full</scopes>
        <scopes>Chatter</scopes>
        <scopes>CustomApplications</scopes>
        <scopes>RefreshToken</scopes>
        <scopes>OpenID</scopes>
        <scopes>CustomPermissions</scopes>
        <scopes>Wave</scopes>
        <scopes>Eclair</scopes>
        <scopes>Pardot</scopes>
        <scopes>Lightning</scopes>
        <scopes>Content</scopes>
        <scopes>CDPIngest</scopes>
    </oauthConfig>
    <oauthPolicy>
        <ipRelaxation>ENFORCE</ipRelaxation>
        <refreshTokenPolicy>infinite</refreshTokenPolicy>
    </oauthPolicy>
</ConnectedApp>
```

You can check the documentaion for the mapping of values to what you see in the UI, but I've copied below the values you'll get with retrieval.

- `Api` - Allows access to the logged-in user’s account over the APIs.
- `Basic` — Allows access to the user’s identity URL service, and includes
  Address, Email, Phone, and Profile.
- `Chatter` — Allows access to only the Connect REST API resources.
- `CustomApplications` — Allows access to custom applications, such as
  those using Visualforce.
- `Full` — Allows access to all data accessible by the logged-in user.
- `OpenID` — Allows access to the logged in user’s unique identifier for
  OpenID Connect apps.
- `CDPIngest` — Allows access to Customer Data Platform (CDP) ingest API
  services. Customers use these API services to upload and maintain
  external data sets in the CDP. Available in API version 52.0 and
  later.
- `CustomPermissions` — Allows access to the custom permissions in an
  organization associated with the connected app, and shows whether the
  current user has each permission enabled.
- `Pardot` — Allows access to Pardot API services on behalf of the user.
  The full extent of accessible services is managed by the Pardot
  account. Available in API version 49.0 and later.
- `Lightning` — Allows hybrid apps to directly obtain Lightning child
  sessions through the OAuth 2.0 hybrid app token flow and hybrid app
  refresh token flow. Available in API version 51.0 and later.
- `Content` — Allows hybrid apps to directly obtain content child sessions
  through the OAuth 2.0 hybrid app token flow and hybrid app refresh
  token flow. Available in API version 51.0 and later.
- `RefreshToken` — Allows a refresh token to be returned if you’re eligible
  to receive one, and is synonymous with allowing OfflineAccess.
- `Wave` — Allows access to the Analytics REST API resources. Available in
  API version 35.0 and later.
- `Eclair` — Allows access to the Analytics REST API Charts Geodata
  resource. Available in API version 35.0 and later.
- `Web` — Allows usage of the access_token on the web. This usage also
  includes visualforce, allowing access to Visualforce pages.

Comment: Thanks Kris, what is the endpoint I should access to get this resoponse?

Comment: I added an edit to provide the Metadata API doc for the `retrieve()` call, but what's the context of your request - is it to ingest with an outside application, to be done within Salesforce, etc?

Comment: Thanks Kris! Actually I want to get all scopes of all applications. I was able to fetch my own applications scopes thru the metadata api at `https://<instace-name>.my.salesforce.com/services/metadata/v52.0/components/connectedApps/<app-name>`, but I didn't see all applications at `https://<instace-name>.my.salesforce.com/services/metadata/v52.0/components/connectedApps`

Comment: correct. That second URL should give you a list of endpoints for each app you can call to get all the scopes for each - though it'll be separate calls for each one. You could group them (25 sub-requests into one) by using [composite API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm)