# Enforce OAuth Scope for Lightning Apps

Tags: lightning, oauth, app, winter22

How to find if any of lightning apps in my org uses oauth. Can anyone please guide me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is within [`ConnectedApp` metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm). If you [pull down this metadata type](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354257/retrieving-oauth-scopes-from-an-installed-connected-app) from the metadata API you'll be able to identify your apps. This should be a good first step for you to identify your apps. That being said, I am not sure what aspects of a ConnectedApp (if anything) identifies it as a "Lightning app" *specifically*. Check for a `startUrl` property - that may be informative.

[Per the Salesforce release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_oauth_ru.htm&type=5&release=234) they can be identified by their URL:

> Lightning apps include Lightning Experience and any resource with a URL that ends with .app before any optional query string.

For each app, check the OAuth `scopes` under `oauthConfig`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedApp xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <contactEmail>test@example.com</contactEmail>
    <label>My App</label>
    <oauthConfig>
        <callbackUrl>https://www.test.com</callbackUrl>
        <consumerKey>the key will be here</consumerKey>
        <isAdminApproved>false</isAdminApproved>
        <isConsumerSecretOptional>false</isConsumerSecretOptional>
        <isIntrospectAllTokens>false</isIntrospectAllTokens>
        <isSecretRequiredForRefreshToken>true</isSecretRequiredForRefreshToken>
        <scopes>Lightning</scopes>
    </oauthConfig>
    <oauthPolicy>
        <ipRelaxation>ENFORCE</ipRelaxation>
        <refreshTokenPolicy>infinite</refreshTokenPolicy>
    </oauthPolicy>
</ConnectedApp>
```

In order for your Lightning app to continue to provide permissions to authenticated users correctly, it must use one of the following 4 scopes (per the release notes). I have placed the actual scope name in bold for emphasis.

> - Allow access to Lightning applications (**lightning**)
> - Provide access to custom applications (**visualforce**)
> - Provide access to your data via the web (**web**)
> - Full access (**full**). Use this option only if none of the other options are sufficient.