# Get OAuth scopes for managed apps using API

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, connected-apps, oauth

I am exploring the Saleforce API in order to obtain the OAuth scopes for connected applications. As an experiment, I created two connected apps:

1. Create a connected app manually say `App1` by clicking on the "New Connected App" or similar button and filling in the details.
2. Install an application from the Salesforce App Exchange say `Slack`.

Both the above apps show up as connected apps within the UI. The `Slack` app is also labeled as `Managed`.

When I however use the Metadata API for fetching the **ConnectedApp** object, the response only contains the data for `App1` and does not include `Slack`. Similarly, I can query for the OAuth scopes for `App1` but not for `Slack`. In the user interface however, I am able to see the OAuth scopes for both the apps when I click on the respective apps.

I wanted to understand how I can obtain the OAuth scopes for any connected app (created manually or installed from App Exchange).

Details about my Salesforce environment: Salesforce with Developer edition.
Query mechanism : Shell script (cURL) / Postman.

Any insights into this aspect would be highly appreciated. This is my first time with Salesforce and I have to admit the API surface appears very vast and scattered with a lot of concepts making it easy to miss out on finer aspects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving oAuth scopes from an installed connected app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354257/retrieving-oauth-scopes-from-an-installed-connected-app)

Comment: @identigral no it really does not. I have already referred that link and the final set of comments on the response where the OP explicitly mentions this point. The response provided to that comment does not explicitly clarify whether the OAuth permissions for installed apps are also retrieved. Also, as this is my first time with SalesForce a more detailed example request and response would help

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.