# Retrieving Scopes of a ConnectedApplication

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, metadata-api, connected-apps

What methods or APIs can be used to obtain the **scopes** associated with a [ConnectedApplication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ConnectedApplication.htm)

Just like I get in [ConnectedApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm#ConnectedAppOauthConfig) -> ConnectedAppOauthConfig

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving oAuth scopes from an installed connected app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354257/retrieving-oauth-scopes-from-an-installed-connected-app)

Comment: No.
cause the answer refers to ConnectedApp and not to ConnectedApplication.

Comment: They're the same thing.

Comment: They are not.

The main difference between these two APIs is their intended use cases. The Connected Apps API is mainly used to enable external applications to access Salesforce data, while the Connected Application API is used to enable custom Salesforce applications to integrate with other Salesforce applications.

For that reason and more, the response you get is totally different.